# How do I set up a listening socket using Rust without having it get dropped by garbage collector

Tags: rust, tcp, rust-cargo

I want to set up socket to listen for incoming connections, and do some logic based on incoming message.

```rust
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};

fn main() {
    set_listening_server("192.168.80.180", 2048);
}

fn set_listening_server(ip: &str, port: i32) {
    assert!(port > 1000 && ip.len() > 0);
    println!("Function is OK!");

    let addr = format!("{}:{}", ip, port);

    let listener = match TcpListener::bind(&addr) {
        Ok(listener) => {
            println!("Listening on {}", &addr);
            loop {}
        }
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Error binding to {}: {}", &addr, e);
            return;
        }
    };
}
```

The above is how I have set up the socket. At first I had the `loop{}` exist right after the `set_listening_server` call but I figured that as soon as the function finished executing that socket was dropped. Moving the loop inside the function call solves those issues, but is there perhaps a way to declare `listener` globally?

I want to have seperate functions to handle steps of the communication, for example if I want to have something like:

```rust
fn service_connection() {
    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        println!("Connection established!");
    }
}
```

How can I access listener if it is being declared inside of the `set_listening_server`?

Would calling this `service_connection` function inside of the loop be the correct approach?

EDIT:

If I want to return the socket how can I do it correctly?

```
fn set_listening_server(ip: &str, port: i32) -> TcpListener{
    assert!(port > 1000 && ip.len() > 0);
    println!("Function is OK!");

    let addr = format!("{}:{}", ip, port);

    let listener = TcpListener::bind(&addr);

    return listener;
}
```

Comment: Rust doesn't have a garbage collector.

Comment: When the listener variable goes out of scope the socket gets dropped, is my best guess. Why I have the loop inside of the set_listening_server function and not main function

Comment: It's not the garbage collector, it's that it *fell out of scope* and was dropped (via `Drop`). Normally what you'd do here is return a `Result` and use that elsewhere. You could restructure this to have a function that just calls `bind` with the combined arguments, returning that value, and move the `match` part elsewhere.

Comment: @tadman How do I return the socket that was created? I put up my attempt in the OP, I'm getting an error that it expects a return type of TCPListener but it receives Result

Comment: The return value of that function should be a `Result<TcpListener, Error>` (presuming `std::io::Error`). It's the responsibility of the caller to unwrap/handle that.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access listener if it is being declared inside of the
> set_listening_server?

```
fn set_listening_server(){
    let listener=TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8000").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming(){
        // this stream is sent by the client
        let stream=stream.unwrap();
        println!("Connection established! {:?}",listener);
        // you have to write a separate function to handle this incoming connection
       handle_incoming_connection(stream)
    } 
}
```

inside `handle_incoming_connection` you read the stream and based on the result you write a response

```
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};

fn handle_incoming_connection(mut stream:TcpStream){
    let buf_reader=BufReader::new(&mut stream);
    //  you have to read the request lines
    let mut request_line=buf_reader.lines().next();
    // based on incoming request route you have to prepare responses


}
```